# Inner div does not respect css max height of outer div

Tags: html, css

I got three divs:

- the grey div is my outer div which defines the height
- the green div is a div which enables the scrolling of
- the red div, which is the content

The following code sample is a minimal example I created to replicate my issue.

```css
.outside {
    max-height: 500px;

    background-color: gray;
}

.inside {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;

    background-color: green;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.content {
    height: 2000px;

    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body style="overflow-y: hidden">
        <div class="outside">
            <div class="inside">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Although the grey div has a max-height of `500px`, the green div gets the height of the red div and does not scroll the content inside.

When setting `height: 100%` to the grey div, the scrolling works as expected for content bigger than the grey divs height. If the content (red div) is smaller, I want the green div to only be the height of its content.

Comment: please copy code into an own html file... it seems to not work as a code snippet here as it does locally in my html file

Comment: did you add the doctype in your local html file?

Comment: yeah, should have mentioned it. This example is a really broken down example of my problem, but it reflects the same problems as in my original code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do this (as already mentioned). In some cases, using viewport height can be problematic on mobile devices. Instead of using vh, turn the gray container into a flex object.

```css
.outside {
    max-height: 500px;
    background-color: gray;
    /* make it a flex container */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.inside {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.content {
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 100px;
    /* make scrolling more obvious */
    background: repeating-linear-gradient(
    -55deg,
    #ff0000,
    #ff0000 10px,
    #cc0c0c 10px,
    #cc0c0c 20px
    );
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div class="outside">
            <div class="inside">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/0fhga6vt/

Comment: In fact, it is not necessary to set `.inside { height: 100%; }` in your solution.

Comment: i will test it the next days, if it solves my problem, too. I seems to solve it for my example

Comment: My solution is to point out the use of flex box. I didn't remove anything from the original post code. Whatever is extraneous should be removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This line you need is overflow: hidden;
The moment you give your stubborn inner div overflow:hidden, it will cut off the extra part.

You should also set the height of the inner div to 100% which implies that it should not go beyond the max height of the parent div.

Comment: What do you mean with setting the height of the inner div to 100%? The .inside div has a height of 100% and according to this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2723784/9353519 the height ignores the max-height of its parent

Answer (score 0):

In order for the inside div (`height: 100%`) to work, the parent `.outside` element must also have a fixed height. Unfortunately `max-height` is does not work as it is not a fixed height. I recommend adding a reasonable height based on the viewport height. The max-height will make sure it gets no bigger than 500px, and the `.inside` element will start working as you expect.

```css
.outside {
    height: 70vh; /* this is the only thing I changed */
    max-height: 500px;
    background-color: gray;
}

.inside {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;

    background-color: green;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.content {
    height: 2000px;

    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body style="overflow-y: hidden">
        <div class="outside">
            <div class="inside">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yea thats my problem. I don't want to add a fixed height to the outer div since it then gets a fixed height instead of the height it needs. 

I had it before with a height of 100%, which works fine. The thing is, that I have content, that only fills half of the height in one tab and in the other tab (in the same inner div) it fills more than the height which is why I need it to scroll

Answer (score 0):

- Since you have only the `inside` div inside the `outside` div, if you used flex box column with `flex: 1` for the `inside` div, the inside div would take its parent height without overflowing.
- This way scrolling will work fine and if the content isn't overflowing, the `outside` div would shrink to the `content` div height.

Feel free to test with different content heights, and if anything is unclear, ask in the comments.

```css
.outside {
    max-height: 500px;
    /* Change */
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    /* Change */
    background-color: gray;
}

.inside {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    /* Change */
    /* with flex: 1; and the only child div of 'outside'
    is the 'inside' div, then the inside would 
    take the full height of its parent without the need to 
    put a fixed height to the parent div 'outside' */ 
    flex: 1;
    /* Change */
    background-color: green;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

.content {
    height: 2000px;

    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body style="overflow-y: hidden">
        <div class="outside">
            <div class="inside">
                <div class="content"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

An elegant `grid` + `fit-content` solution:

```css
.outside {
  background-color: gray;
  /*  */
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: fit-content(500px);
}

.inside {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: green;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.content {
  height: 2000px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, blue);
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
  <div class="inside">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

***P.S.** If you also want to fit of window height:*

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
}

.outside {
  background-color: gray;
  /*  */
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: fit-content( min(500px, 100vh) );
}

.inside {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  background-color: green;
  margin-right: 100px;
}

.content {
  height: 2000px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red, blue);
  margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="outside">
  <div class="inside">
    <div class="content"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the parent container to display as flex and use flex-grow property to make the green div expand to fill the remaining space. Here's an example code:

```css
.outside {
    max-height: 500px;
    background-color: gray;
    display: flex;
}

.inside {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background-color: green;
    margin-right: 100px;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.content {
    height: 2000px;
    background-color: red;
    margin-right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body style="overflow-y: hidden">
    <div class="outside">
        <div class="inside">
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

With this code, the green div will expand to fill the remaining space when the content is smaller than the grey div's height, and it will scroll the content inside when it's bigger.